# Deleting qgis setup.exe from download folder

Tags: qgis, windows, memory

I need to clean up the download folder in order to liberate space in C drive, but I have realised that the file qgis setup.exe is in this folder.

Can I delete the qgis setup.exe file from the download folder without affecting qgis software?

I guess that yes, but I wanted to be sure before making a possible mistake.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS will not store anything in the downloads folder.

You should be safe to delete it.

Although the actual installer for the current version of QGIS on Windows is:
QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.26.3-1.msi

From: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html